# Django ManyToMany get error 'Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable'

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

i have this issue on my application.
`Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable`
In fact, i creating an application in which we have a relationship of the type several Products inone or more Orders.

Here is my code :

`models.py`

```
# model Product
class Products(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    class Meta:
        db_table ="products"


# model Order
class Orders(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    order_number = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    supply = models.ForeignKey(Supplies, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    statut = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="validé")
    date_of_order = models.DateField()
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Products, through='OrderProduct')
    class Meta:
        db_table ="orders"


# model OrderProduct
class OrderProduct(models.Model):
    Order = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    class Meta:
        db_table ="ordersproducts"
```

`views.py`

```
# OrderGetAllApi
@csrf_exempt
def order_list(request):
    orders = Orders.objects.select_related('supply').all
    # orders = Orders.objects.select_related('products').all()

    order_list = []
    for order in orders:
        order_list.append({
            'order_id': order.order_id,
            'order_number': order.order_number,
            'date_of_order': order.date_of_order,
            'supply_id': order.supply.supply_id,
            'supply_name': order.supply.supply_name,
            'supply_address': order.supply.supply_address,
            'products': order.products.all()
        })
    return JsonResponse(order_list, safe=False)
```

`serializers.py`

```
class OrderProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = ProductSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = OrderProduct
        fields = ['product_id', 'product_name', 'product_quantity']
        # fields = '_all_'


class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    supply = SupplySerializer()
    products = OrderProductSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model=Orders
        fields=('order_id', 'order_number', 'date_of_order', 'statut', 'supply', 'products')
```

I want to get the list of order with their respective products.
when i enter the list od orders (order_list) in the browser
And i get the error `Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable`.
How can fix the problem and get the list of Orders with their products.

Thank You

Comment: The first step in debugging is to take a closer look at the error. For example the error will tell you on which line in which function did the error occur. This is also useful information to include in the question.

Comment: ...in this case it's quite easy to find though, the error says "Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable" and we can see on this line `'products': order.products.all()` you are giving it a queryset to serialize to JSON

Comment: essentially what you're doing in the view already is take the `orders` queryset and make a list of dictionaries which can be serialized, so you need to make another list of dictionaries from `order.products.all()` and use that as the value of `'products'`

Comment: if you find you have many views where you need to serialize queryset to JSON you should take a look at Django REST Framework, a library on top of Django that provides helper classes for doing exactly that https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the good code:

```
order_list = []
for order in orders:
  order_list.append({
    'order_id': order.order_id,
    'order_number': order.order_number,
    'date_of_order': order.date_of_order,
    'supply_id': order.supply.supply_id,
    'supply_name': order.supply.supply_name,
    'supply_address': order.supply.supply_address,
    'products': list(order.products.values()) 
  })
return JsonResponse(order_list, safe=False)
```

)

Answer (score 1):

You pass this to your JSONResponse but it's queryset and it's not serializable.

```
'products': order.products.all()
```

You need to either convert it to list of dicts or use Serializer.

Comment: OK, i see, how can I either convert it to list of dicts or use Serializer, im new in Django. Thank you.